# Como resumir um texto dentro do <span>?

Tags: css

Bom tenho o seguinte código:

```
<span>TÍTULO CONTAINER TEXO TEXTO TEXO TEXTO</span>
```

Preciso que este `span` tenha `width: 100%` e que não tenha quebra de linha, se o texto for muito grande ele tem que resumir e colocar (`...`).

Tem como fazer isso com css?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode definir o [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) como *ellipsis* no seu estilo:

```
span {
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce maximus dui eu libero facilisis venenatis. Pellentesque placerat vulputate semper. </span>
```

Comment: Uma dica, sempre pesquise antes e de preferencia marque a resposta como dup, mesmo que você venha a responde-la http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=ellipsis%20%5bcss%5d

Comment: tem como fazer isso sem o 'width: 100%;'?

Comment: Concordo @GuilhermeNascimento, também marquei :P

Comment: No exemplo que dei o width está 100% @HugoBorges, não é isso?

Comment: sim isso mesmo.